# Is it possible to reverse the Context Menu items or reverse the sort

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding `Context Items` for a `Context Menu` and showing the required `Items` where necessary for the user based on user selection. I would like to show these `context items` for the user `NEW` and `CLOSE`..

I did some thing like

```
ContextMenu.Add(NEW)
ContextMenu.Add(CLOSE)
```

But I am getting this in sorted order like `CLOSE` first and `NEW` last . But I need to display `NEW` first and `CLOSE` last. Is it possible to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (very basic code) should do it. Place following code in the constructor of your Form:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("New"));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Close"));
this.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

*Note:* you still have to add the events yourself... :)

**Update:**

To add events to the items you'll have to declare them in a variable instead of passing them directly in the Add() method for the MenuItems. So the previous code will look like this:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

var itemOne = new MenuItem("New");
itemOne.Click += ContextMenuItemClick;
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(itemOne);

var itemTwo = new MenuItem("Close");
itemTwo.Click += ContextMenuItemClick;    
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(itemTwo);

ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

As you can see, bot items have the same eventhandler for the Click-event. In that event you check which item was clicked. That code looks like this:

```
private void ContextMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    switch(selectedItem.Text)
    {
        case "New" : //do some new stuff
            break;
        case "Close": //do some closing stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that you could also set a separate eventhandler for each item in the menu, but then you end up with lots of methods for basically the same stuff... :) Hope this helps!

**Update2:**

With all the help I gave, you normally should have been able to achieve this by yourself, not? :) Anyway, for a separate handler the code will look like this:

```
itemOne.Click += itemOne_Click;
itemTwo.Click += itemTwo_Click;

private void itemOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do the new stuff
}

private void itemTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do the closing stuff
}
```

**Update3:**

If you gave proper names to the menuitems you already added, you can change the order using the Index-property. Say I have following menuitems added to a ContextMenu:

```
var itemOne = new MenuItem("New") { Name = "NewItem" };
var itemTwo = new MenuItem("Close") { Name = "CloseItem" };
```

The 'NewItem' will be the first item and the 'CloseItem' will be the second. Now if I want to change the order **without touching previous code** you can do this:

```
contextMenu.MenuItems["NewItem"].Index = 1;
```

This will set the 'CloseItem' as the first and the 'NewItem' as the second. If you have more than 2 items, you better set the Index-property for each item individually.

Comment: Is it possible with the default items I have

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to do as per i asked why because i have to make changes through out my application

Comment: I didn't asked for separate click what I am asking is I already have `Items` for context menu can I arrange them in the way I required, with out adding dynamical Items

Comment: No offence, but you DID ask for this: "how can I write Individual event as per your code". And if you're adding the items yourself, you can add them the way I did, this way they will appear in the order you want. Check my answer again for another possible solution.

Comment: @User : check 'Update3' section of my answer.